# Difference between charging icons - does it mean anything?

Tags: charging, power, power-management, power-mac

Sometimes I see this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

instead of this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

is there a difference? do they mean different things? One is filled in dark, the other is more transparent - the battery/charge icon..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Empty battery icon with lightning bolt means the device is plugged-in and using power but the battery is not charging.  Your Mac is using power directly from the cord.

[image]

---

Full battery icon with lightning bolt means the device is plugged-in and the battery is charging.  Your Mac can use power from both the cord and battery.

[image]

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: My 10 years of Mac usage experience and memory (so it still might be faulty :-p )

Comment: I can dig up a command to show this and edit later in the weekend. fsb is correct.

Comment: This is wrong, at least for me on Catalina. Opening the battery drop-down menu shows me "empty battery" icon is charging my battery, and "full battery" icon is not.

Comment: This is the wrong answer (at least in Mojave). The opposite is true. The other answer explains more.

Comment: @Thanassis the answer was correct for the person who asked it, that's why it was accepted.  Just stating something is 'wrong' is not very helpful. If you feel it should be improved for Mojave, feel free to edit the answer to add the Mojave-specific info.

Comment: I think my comment contains enough information about what is wrong and includes the qualifier about Mojave. I cannot test older or newer versions of macOS to test whether your answer is right in these cases. I do not want to make a half-baked edit on the answer. I believe a comment was the most appropriate response. Since you are still active you are probably the best person to edit this answer, taking into account the other answer, which provides valuable info about **how** to test if the battery is charging or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Lightning + empty battery** icon means the battery **is** charging.

**Lightning + full battery** icon means the battery **isn't** charging.

You can confirm by clicking the battery indicator, and the drop-down menu will tell you if the battery is charging or not:

[image]

("2:44 until full" is referring to battery recharging)

[image]

Additional source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6751144

The design of the icons seemed counter-intuitive to me at first, but I guess it makes sense if you think in terms of power source:

**Battery only** (i.e. when not plugged in) - battery is supplying power

**Lightning only** - the power cord is supplying power (allowing the battery to recharge)

**Lightning + battery** - BOTH the power cord AND the battery are supplying power (so the battery is not being recharged)(note: this also appears when the battery is fully charged)

Comment: Note: this is clearer on Monterey. It shows a plug when not charging, and a lightning bolt when charging.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer (at least in Mojave). The accepted answer is wrong. I am checking this on my  MacBook Air.

Comment: @mblakesley is correct! This entire answer thread has needed to continually update alongside releases as there's a lot of outdated info here...